# How to unzip cifar10/100 database manually?

Tags: python

i want to train my neural network with cifar10 dataset. i have both datasets on my harddrive and i can unzip the folder and import the bash files, but i want a solution for the import of these data i can understand and learn it!

have anyone a simple, for a newbie "learnable" piece of code ?
you can also explain me line by line what this code does and pls like you speking with a 6 year old child :D

```
import pickle 
import sys
from keras import backend as K
from keras.utils import to_categorical

def load_batch(fpath, label_key='labels'):

with open(fpath, 'rb') as f:
    if sys.version_info < (3,):
        d = pickle.load(f)
    else:
        d = pickle.load(f, encoding='bytes')
        # decode utf8
        d_decoded = {}
        for k, v in d.items():
            d_decoded[k.decode('utf8')] = v
        d = d_decoded
data = d['data']
labels = d[label_key]

data = data.reshape(data.shape[0], 3, 32, 32)
return data, labels


 def load_data():

path = 'cifar-10-batches-py'

num_train_samples = 50000

x_train_local = np.empty((num_train_samples, 3, 32, 32), dtype='uint8')
y_train_local = np.empty((num_train_samples,), dtype='uint8')

for i in range(1, 6):
    fpath = os.path.join(path, 'data_batch_' + str(i))
    (x_train_local[(i - 1) * 10000: i * 10000, :, :, :],
     y_train_local[(i - 1) * 10000: i * 10000]) = load_batch(fpath)

fpath = os.path.join(path, 'test_batch')
x_test_local, y_test_local = load_batch(fpath)

y_train_local = np.reshape(y_train_local, (len(y_train_local), 1))
y_test_local = np.reshape(y_test_local, (len(y_test_local), 1))

if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_last':
    x_train_local = x_train_local.transpose(0, 2, 3, 1)
    x_test_local = x_test_local.transpose(0, 2, 3, 1)

return (x_train_local, y_train_local), (x_test_local, y_test_local)

  (x_train, x_label), (y_train, y_label) = load_data()
  print('x_train shape:', x_train.shape)
  print('y_train shape:', y_train.shape)
  print(x_train.shape[0], 'train samples')
  print(x_test.shape[0], 'test samples')

  x_label = to_categorical(x_label)
  y_label = to_categorical(y_label)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the files on your hard drive. Go to that folder, open up a terminal there. Start with `from glob import glob`. Use glob to get the name of all files. Then, use OpenCV for reading the files using `cv2.imread`. Then, use numpy to get means, and other things. For viewing the files use:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.imshow(file_object_you_get_from_opencv)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Learn to play around with these. If you need help, comment here.